# One more recurrence relation degree 3 problem.

Tags: combinatorics

If you can answer one I would be forever thankful. I'm doing them right now and I just want to check my work on here. I know you start with getting the characteristic equation x^3=6x^2-12x+8 for the first etc.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

(a) Since the equation $x^3 - 6x^2 +128 -8 = 0$ has a triple root at $x=2$, the general solution will be 
$$a_n = 2^n (ax^2+bx+c)
$$
Then for $n=0$ we get 
$$
c = a_0 = -4
$$
and for $n=1$ we get
$$
2a+2b +2\cdot(-4) = a_1 = 4 \Longrightarrow a+b = 6
$$and for $n=2$ we get
$$
16a+8b +4\cdot(-4) = a_2 = 8 \Longrightarrow 2a+b = 3 \Longrightarrow a = -3, b = 9
$$
so the answer is 
$$
a_n = 2^n(-3n^2+9n-4)$$

(b) This time the characteristic equation has 3 distinct roots, $(-3, -1, +1)$ so we have
a general solution 
$$a_n = a\cdot(-3)^n + b \cdot(-1)^n + c $$
which for $n=0, 1, 2$ gives 
$$ \left\{ \begin{array}{c} a+b+c = 5 \\
-3a -b + c = -9 \\
9a + b + c = 15
\end{array}\right. \Longrightarrow a = \frac{5}{4}, b = \frac{18}{4}, c=-\frac{3}{4}$$
so the solution is 
$$
a_n = \frac{1}{4} \left( 5\cdot (-3)^n +  18\cdot (-1)^n - 3\right)$$